# jquery slider not working for DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a jquery carousel slider that slides whole divs on and off the screen. When I hover over the images, it doesn't do anything.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rightcolumn').bxSlider();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="rightcolumn">
<img  src="" class="imageright" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; "/>
<img  src="Images/Interior-Main-Base.png" class="imageright main" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; "/>
<img id="Kitchen1e" src="Images/enabled.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Kitchen2e" src="Images/tiny.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Third_Car1e" src="Images/Interior-Main-3rd Car.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Third_Car2e" src="Images/tiny111.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Laundry_Up1e" src="Images/Interior-Main-Laundry Up.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Laundry_Up2e" src="Images/tiny113.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Open_Great1e" src="Images/Interior-Main-Open Great.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Open_Great2e" src="Images/tiny115.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="KitchenMouseover" src="Images/Interior-Main-2' Kitchen.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Third_CarMouseover" src="Images/Interior-upper-3rd10.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Laundry_UpMouseover" src="Images/Interior-Main-Laundry Up11.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
<img id="Open_GreatMouseover" src="Images/Interior-Main-Open Great12.png" style="visibility:hidden" class="imageright"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rightcolumn').bxSlider();
});
 </script>
 <ul id="rightcolumn">
  <li><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

download 
 1. jquery.bxslider.min.js and
 2. jquery.bxslider.css
 from here http://bxslider.com/